# What is the concept of CNTKTextFormatDeserializer and why use?

Tags: cntk

I am using the CNTKTextReader to read in my training and test sets.  The train file is getting large ( 2.7 GB now, and soon to get bigger ).

I don't understand what is "CNTKTextFormatDeserializer" -- the doc I found didn't explain what the big picture is -- what is it and why use it?  The doc I found just went into syntax of it.

So, is it a way to use a binary version of these files to make them more compact?

Answer (score 0):

Readers in general are just a way to make certain aspects of training easier. These include

1. **randomization**: SGD generalizes better when the data presented to it are coming in random order. The reader can randomize the data for you with shuffling happening on the fly.
2. **distributed training**: For distributed training the reader is aware of the multiple workers and can make sure they receive distinct chunks of data.
3. **memory budget issues**: The reader does not load the whole training file in memory.
4. **language agnostic i/o**: The reader provides a cross-platform way to read data. (if you want to always be in Python, you might not care about this but others do).

The CTF format is a little verbose and indeed there is a [binary format deserializer](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.io.html#cntk.io.CBFDeserializer) that was recently added.